# No route matches "/oauth/authorize"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, authlogic, omniauth

I've started integrating Omniauth 1.0 into my Rails/Authlogic application and I get a route error when I try to access `localhost:3000/auth/facebook`.

Are we supposed to create a custom route for each `/auth/strategy` we want, or is there something else wrong here?

```
# gemfile
gem 'omniauth-facebook'

# routes
resources :authentications
match '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'authentications#create'

# config/initializers/omniauth.rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, '20...', 'bc...'
end

# accessing /auth/facebook
No route matches "/oauth/authorize"
```

Answer (score 7):

Updated my GemFile with

```
gem "omniauth-facebook", :git => "git://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook.git"
```

and it worked.

Comment: Ben - I'm getting `invalid_uri` from Facebook for trying to connect through `localhost`. Do you know what this is about?

Comment: @sscirrus This is probably a Facebook setting. Facebook requires a redirect URI be set (although they now allow multiple). You can modify it by updating your app at https://developers.facebook.com/.

Comment: This is a temp fix since the new FB omniauth gem isn't officially released yet. Likely fixed soon as it's an RC.